# display line breaks asp.net mvc razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, textarea, line-breaks

I'm using the following to make the text output the line breaks entered in a `<textarea>` HTML element.

```
MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.Post.Description.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />"))
```

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: I don't really see how this helper outputs any line breaks as you are replacing line breaks with a space.

Comment: @Darin - poor copy/pasting on my part,  updated.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032097/asp-net-mvc-convert-n-new-line-to-html-breaks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace line break characters with <br /> in ASP.NET MVC Razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220381/replace-line-break-characters-with-br-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-view)

Answer (score 105, accepted):

There's an even better/awesome solution that employs [CSS white-space property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp):

Using this you avoid [Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) (XSS) vulnerabilities...

```
<p style="white-space: pre-line">@Model.Message</p>
```

Works like a charm with ASP.NET MVC Razor engine.

Comment: This should be in fact the accepted answer. Because the op ask for a nicer way !

Answer (score 24):

Your code is vulnerable to XSS attacks as it doesn't HTML encode the text. I would recommend you the following:

```
var result = string.Join(
    "<br/>",
    Model.Post.Description
        .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
        .Select(x => HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x))
);
return MvcHtmlString.Create(result);
```

and then in your view you can safely:

```
@Html.SomeHelper()
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can output the text inside a <pre> tag.

Comment: simple but working, thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Just use a tag.
        `<pre>@Model.Post.Description</pre>`

Or

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Post.Description.Replace("\r\n", "<br>")))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me.

```
<p class="message">
@Html.Raw("<p>" + Model.Text + "</p>")
</p>
```

string Model.Text having < br/> tag inside.

Comment: That is open to XSS attack. Place `<script>alert('XSS')'</script>` into you `Model.Text` and you have a vuln.

Comment: @trailmax then come with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(Regex.Replace(Html.Encode(Model.Address), Environment.NewLine, "<br />", RegexOptions.Multiline))
```

and of course, you will have to add following using statement for Regex to work.

```
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Hope it is useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following command as it has filtering enabled:

`<p style="white-space: pre-line" <p>`

Comment: How is this different form the accepted answer?