# New line character from c# to cshtml

Tags: c#, html, razor

I am making a webpage... the controller is written in C# and the webpage is in cshtml. In the c# file, I am constructing strings to be put into the table on the html page. When I have my strings, I need line breaks within them, so I have things like stringpart1 + "\n" + stringpart2 in hope of the webpage displaying the string as two separate lines as I fill my table cells. However, everything seems to print out on the same line. I have also tried "\r\n" and System.Environment.NewLine instead. Any ideas as to a potential fix?

Comment: Try stringpart1 + "<br/>" + stringpart2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display line breaks asp.net mvc razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276688/display-line-breaks-asp-net-mvc-razor)

Comment: dnickless I have already tried that, Samvel Petrosov Ill look into that

Comment: I want do do the same thing. Anyone have a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix which worked for me. In your .cshtml, use this:
`@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode([your content containing \n]))`

Comment: That works. However, if you fill it with content from a variable that can be set by a user, than you have a potential XSS. So only use it for fixed, known data.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks in HTML are represented by `<br>` tag. Change `\n` and/or `\r` to `<br>`.

Example:

```
part1 + "<br>" + part2;
```

Comment: that was the first thing I tried it just adds <br> literally to the string