# How can you add a next line in a view (MVC4)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an webapplication written in MVC4/Razor. And I try to add a next line in my view dynamically.
How can I do that?

I have tried this with "`<br />`" and "&10;&13;" too.

In the controller

```
exmaple.References = anExample.References.Replace(";", ";/r/n");
exmaple.Methods.AddRange(anExample.Methods);
exampleList.Add(example);
```

In the view

```
      <p>
                <span class="label">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Methods)</span>
                @{ 
                    foreach (var method in item.Methods)
                    {
                        <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => method)</span>
                    }
                }
            </p>
```

Result:

References using System;/r/n using System.ComponentModel;/r/n

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032097/asp-net-mvc-convert-n-new-line-to-html-breaks maybe

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Environment.NewLine as a line break in the model, but whatever you want works. 
 In the view:

```
 foreach(var method in item.Methods){
       Html.Raw(method.Replace("[whatever line break character you have]", "<br />"))
 }
```